# Create table taking much longer than select sql oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a select query running on an oracle database that takes only about fifteen seconds to run. However when I try to create a table from this, either using a create select as or creating a blank table and inserting the rows, the create just keeps running and running (so far I've waited up to fifteen minutes with no result).

Below is my attempt at the create blank then insert method, which shows the structure of the table I'm creating and the data I'm trying to insert:

```
CREATE TABLE MYNEWTABLE
(mykey number(10), brand varchar2(255), day_id number(10), adateone date, p_id number (10), startdate date, enddate date, another_day_id number(10))
INSERT INTO MYNEWTABLE
select ns.mykey, ns.brand, oc.day_id, oc.day_date as adateone, tbut.p_id, tbut.startdate, tbut.enddate, cust.another_day_id
from TABLE_1 ns
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_2 tbut
ON ns.mykey = tbut.mykey
LEFT JOIN
TABLE_3 cust
ON ns.mykey = cust.mykey
LEFT JOIN DATE_TABLE oc
on cust.first_del_day_id = oc.day_id
where ns.brand = 'SOME VALUE'
```

What is the cause of the table's creation being so slow and how can I improve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When any session hangs, the appropriate thing to check is `V$SESSION_WAIT`.

Execute,

```
select * from v$session_wait where sid = <your sid>
```

Depending on the result of the wait, you need to figure out which session is holding the lock you are waiting for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your SQL runs using nested loops. So 15 seconds it is time to return first N rows (where n depends on your client tool). When you start to fetch all rows and insert into new table it takes more time.